# With Spatialite, how do I run PtDistWithin with meters?

Tags: spatialite, srid, within

So the problem is that I have a set of multipolygons and points and I need to be able to query the data with a given point to check which ones are within 'x' km.

Initially my SRID was 4283 but I was unable to figure out a way to use the PtDistWithin function with meters as it used degrees.  I tried loading the data with a SRID of 3577 which should be in meters and querying but I don't get a sensible result.  The query below is my attempt to get the data with 3577 SRID data.

`select * from geotable where PtDistWithin(Transform(PointFromText('POINT(144.963, -37.8136)', 4283), 3577), geotable.geom, 10000);`

This however does not return any result when I know there should be a number of results returned within 10 km of this point.

Note: I know there is an approximate conversion between degrees and meters but am looking for a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 1):

Usage of PtDistWithin is documented in http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-latest.html

> return TRUE (1) if the distance between geom1 and geom2 is within the
> given range. Usually distances are expressed in the length unit
> corresponding to the geoms own SRID: but if both geoms are simple
> POINTs and their SRID is 4326 (i.e. WGS84), then distances are
> expressed in meters. In this later case the optional arg use_spheroid
> can be used to select the distance algorithm to be used: is
> use_spheroid = 1 the slowest but most accurate geodesic distance will
> be evaluated: in any other case the simplest great circle distance
> will be used instead

SpatiaLite is feature-rich but it seems that it can't handle your use case with PtDistWithin because you have multipolygons. If your data are within the valid area of EPSG:3577 you can make a conversion into that. Othewise you may have a try with another function "Distance" in query SELECT...FROM...WHERE Distance(geom1,geom2)<10000. I am not sure if you can use EPSG:4283 with that function or if you must transform it into EPSG:4326.

> return the distance between geom1 and geom2 (measured in meters). If
> the use_ellipsoid argument is set to TRUE the precise (but slower)
> distance will be computed on the Ellipsoid, otherwise will be computed
> on the Great Cicle (approximative, but faster).
>
> This function only supports Long/Lat coordinates, and will return NULL
> for any planar CRS